# Error when trying to run SFML code

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm getting an error whenever I try to run my SFML program:

> The procedure entry point _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

sf::TcpSocket socket;
sf::IpAddress sender;
unsigned short port;

int main() {
    char data[100];
    std::size_t received;

    // TCP socket:
    if (socket.receive(data, 100, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        // error...
    }
    std::cout << "Received " << received << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // UDP socket:
    //sf::IpAddress sender;
    //unsigned short port;
    //if (socket.receive(data, 100, received, sender, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    //{
        // error...
    //}
    std::cout << "Received " << received << " bytes from " << sender << " on port " << port << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you have linked to a version of SFML that was not built for your compiler. You should make sure you have the right version. You could also build it yourself, making sure it's going to work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a real noob... How do I know if I have the right version?  And how do I build SFML myself?

Comment: Well you should know what compiler you have, and which version of SFML you downloaded. And to build SFML yourself, nothing like their official [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/compile-with-cmake.php).

Comment: I'm using cmake to build, but I keep getting this error:  The program can't start because libgmp-10.dll is missing from your computer.  I looked, the file libgmp-10.dll IS in the bin folder.  Help?

Comment: Is your executable in the bin folder? The bin folder might not be the working directory from which your IDE launches your software.

Comment: The one you built probably. If it asks for a dll file, that means you are trying to run something.

Comment: But I haven't gotten to that part... I'm trying to build it but it keeps telling me libgmp-10.dll is missing

Comment: Again, if it requires a dll file, that's an executable. Make sure you read it carefully.